# Tab bar controllers with coordinators

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I use coordinator pattern in my app, but I have problem with instantiate view controllers. The problem is that I use different module for each tab bar controller.

So far I've used this approach

```
protocol Storyboarded {
    static func instantiate() -> Self
}

extension Storyboarded where Self: UIViewController {

    static func instantiate() -> Self {
        let id = String(describing: self)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        return storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: id) as! Self
    }
}
```

And during creation tab bar coordinator:

```
class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController, Storyboarded {
    
    let main = MainCoordinator(navigationController: UINavigationController())
    let calendar = CalendarCoordinator(navigationController: UINavigationController())
    let chart = ChartCoordinator(navigationController: UINavigationController())
    let profile = ProfileCoordinator(navigationController: UINavigationController())
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        main.start()
        calendar.start()
        chart.start()
        profile.start()
        
        viewControllers = [main.navigationController, calendar.navigationController, chart.navigationController, profile.navigationController]
    }
```

My all view controllers conform to Storyboarded Protocol:

```
  class HomeTableViewController: UIViewController, Storyboarded {}
```

And coordinator for each tab bar controller looks like this

```
    class MainCoordinator: Coordinator {
      
        var childCoordinators = [Coordinator]()
        var navigationController: UINavigationController
        
        init(navigationController: UINavigationController) {
            self.navigationController = navigationController
        }
        
        func start() {
            let vc = HomeTableViewController.instantiate()
            vc.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Home", image: UIImage(systemName: "home"), tag: 0)
            navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
        }
        
    }
```

The problem is that other tab bar controllers belong to others storyboard, not only "Main". Using instantiate() from protocol causes error. I wonder how to create protocol extension where I can initialise ViewControllers with different storyboard names, not only "Main".

Answer (score 0):

Try add this:

```
protocol Storyboarded {

    static var storyboardName: String { get }
    static func instantiate() -> Self
}

extension Storyboarded where Self: UIViewController {

    static var storyboardName: String {
        "Main" // Default implementation
    }

    static func instantiate() -> Self {
        let id = String(describing: self)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: Self.storyboardName, bundle: Bundle.main)
        return storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: id) as! Self
    }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
extension HomeTableViewController: Storyboarded {

    class var storyboardName: String {
        "Home" // Other storyboard name here, overrides default implementation
    }
}
```